# Magento2 hosted payment module

Tags: magento-2.1, payment-methods

I have created magento2 hosted payment module, and I used `sales_place_order_after event`, and the order is created and I redirected to hosted payment page after the payment success I redirect to success page, and I changed the order status from pending to processing. But I can't be able to load the success page because quote is cleared. If this way is correct or any other way is available, please tell me.